# Codeigiter Multiple Login, Session has confused on Centos Server with Cpanel

Tags: codeigniter, session, nginx, ubuntu-server, proxmox

Sorry in advance, I'm not used to English. I build an web application with codeigniter, i use the Session for make a multiple login and the server is Centos Servers with nginx and cpanel. my problem is when user login and other user login in my application and request to the one of page and request together and that happened my user session is confused. I don't know why the server cannot consistently save and return session values ​​to the right user. but when i run my web aplication in ubuntu server, and what happened is no problem at all

Comment: I ever facing similar issue, turns out it happens on shared hosting, I solved it by enabling the csrf config in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function create_token() {
    // **Please created token for every user login time**
    $uuid = array(
        'time_low' => 0,
        'time_mid' => 0,
        'time_hi' => 0,
        'clock_seq_hi' => 0,
        'clock_seq_low' => 0,
        'node' => array()
    );

    $uuid['time_low'] = mt_rand(0, 0xffff) + (mt_rand(0, 0xffff) << 16);
    $uuid['time_mid'] = mt_rand(0, 0xffff);
    $uuid['time_hi'] = (4 << 12) | (mt_rand(0, 0x1000));
    $uuid['clock_seq_hi'] = (1 << 7) | (mt_rand(0, 128));
    $uuid['clock_seq_low'] = mt_rand(0, 255);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $uuid['node'][$i] = mt_rand(0, 255);
    }

    $uuid = sprintf('%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x', $uuid['time_low'], $uuid['time_mid'], $uuid['time_hi'], $uuid['clock_seq_hi'], $uuid['clock_seq_low'], $uuid['node'][0], $uuid['node'][1], $uuid['node'][2], $uuid['node'][3], $uuid['node'][4], $uuid['node'][5]
    );

    return $uuid;
}
```